# Why does Input not storing inputted data in modelValue Prop

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, primevue

I have read several posts on Vue 3 regarding `v-model` and `:value`.
But none of those really helped me in this case.

I want to store value in `modelValue` prop and wanna update it whenever it gets updated or inputted by user.

This code runs without any errors but shows `modelValue: undefined` in Vue 3 Dev Console.

**My Vue code:**

```
    <template>
  <span :class="wrapperClass">
    <i :class="iconLeft" v-if="iconLeft" />
    <InputText
      :type="type"
      :value="modelValue"
      :class="{ 'p-filled': filled }"
      @input="onInput"
    />
    <label for="username">{{ label }}</label>
    <i :class="iconRight" v-if="iconRight" />
  </span>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import InputText from "primevue/inputtext"
import { defineComponent } from "vue"
export default defineComponent({
  name: "FormInput",
  emits: ["update:modelValue"],
  components: { InputText },
  props: {
    iconLeft: {
      type: String,
      default: "",
    },
    iconRight: {
      type: String,
      default: "",
    },
    error: {
      type: String,
      default: "",
    },
    label: {
      type: String,
      default: "",
    },
    type: {
      type: String,
    },
    modelValue: {
      type: String,
    },
  },
  computed: {
    wrapperClass(): any {
      return {
        "p-float-label": true,
        "p-input-icon-left": this.iconLeft,
        "p-input-icon-right": this.iconRight,
      }
    },
    filled(): any {
      return this.modelValue != null && this.modelValue.toString().length > 0
    },
  },
  methods: {
    onInput(event: any): any {
      this.$emit("update:modelValue", event.target.value)
    },
  },
})
</script>
```

**Parent Component:**

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <Example :example="{ heading: 'fii' }" />
    <Button label="Test" />
    <hr />
    <img alt="Vue logo" src="../assets/logo.png" />
    <hr />
    <FormInput v-bind="args" />

    <hr />

    <HelloWorld msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js + TypeScript App" />
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue"
import HelloWorld from "../components/HelloWorld.vue" // @ is an alias to /src
import Example from "../components/Example/Example.vue" // @ is an alias to /src
import FormInput from "../components/Form/FormInput.vue"

export default defineComponent({
  name: "Home",
  components: {
    HelloWorld,
    Example,
    FormInput,
  },
  setup() {
    return {
      args: {
        label: "test",
        type: "text",
        value: "",
      },
    }
  },
})
</script>
```

**Please see this screenshot**

[image: Vue dev console]

**Parent Component in Dev Console**

[image]

Comment: Show parent component

Comment: added screenshot from Parent component, do want to see code?

Comment: Code added from parent component

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are few things to fix:

1. PrimeVue component `InputText` has no prop `value` but `modelValue` (to support `v-model`) - [InputText Docs](https://www.primefaces.org/primevue/showcase/#/inputtext) + read [Using v-model on Components](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-basics.html#using-v-model-on-components) to learn a difference between `v-model` on native inputs vs custom components
2. `InputText` is not a native `input` element, so there is no point to listen for a `input` event. The component is emitting `update:modelValue` event. Also event payload is not native event so `event.target.value` makes no sense, just use `value` - [source](https://github.com/primefaces/primevue/blob/master/src/components/inputtext/InputText.vue)
3. There is no point in duplicating the `p-filled` as `InputText` does this already (see source above)

```js
// FormInput.vue

<template>
  <span :class="wrapperClass">
    <i :class="iconLeft" v-if="iconLeft" />
    <InputText
      :type="type"
      :modelValue="modelValue"
      @update:model-value="onInput"
    />
    <label for="username">{{ label }}</label>
    <i :class="iconRight" v-if="iconRight" />
  </span>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import InputText from "primevue/inputtext"
import { defineComponent } from "vue"

export default defineComponent({
  name: "FormInput",
  emits: ["update:modelValue"],
  components: { InputText },
  props: {
    iconLeft: {
      type: String,
      default: "",
    },
    iconRight: {
      type: String,
      default: "",
    },
    error: {
      type: String,
      default: "",
    },
    label: {
      type: String,
      default: "",
    },
    type: {
      type: String,
      default: "text"
    },
    modelValue: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
  },
  computed: {
    wrapperClass(): any {
      return {
        "p-float-label": true,
        "p-input-icon-left": this.iconLeft,
        "p-input-icon-right": this.iconRight,
      }
    },
  },
  methods: {
    onInput(value: any): any {
      this.$emit("update:modelValue", value)
    },
  },
})
</script>
```

Usage:

```html
<FormInput v-model="data" />
<!-- OR -->
<FormInput :modelValue="data" @update:model-value="data = $event" />
```

Demo:

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      text: "default value",
    }
  },
});

app.component('FormInput', {
  emits: ["update:modelValue"],
  components: {
    'inputtext': primevue.inputtext
  },
  template: `
  <span :class="wrapperClass">
    <i :class="iconLeft" v-if="iconLeft" />
    <inputtext
      :type="type"
      :modelValue="modelValue"
      @update:model-value="onInput"
    ></inputtext>
    <label for="username">{{ label }}</label>
    <i :class="iconRight" v-if="iconRight" />
  </span>
  `,
  props: {
    iconLeft: {
      type: String,
      default: "",
    },
    iconRight: {
      type: String,
      default: "",
    },
    error: {
      type: String,
      default: "",
    },
    label: {
      type: String,
      default: "",
    },
    type: {
      type: String,
      default: "text"
    },
    modelValue: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
  },
  computed: {
    wrapperClass() {
      return {
        "p-float-label": true,
        "p-input-icon-left": this.iconLeft,
        "p-input-icon-right": this.iconRight,
      }
    },
  },
  methods: {
    onInput(value) {
      this.$emit("update:modelValue", value)
    },
  },
});

app.mount('#app');
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/primevue/resources/themes/saga-blue/theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://unpkg.com/primevue/resources/primevue.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://unpkg.com/primeicons/primeicons.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/primevue/inputtext/inputtext.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <form-input v-model="text"></form-input>
  <pre>
    {{ text }}
  </pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but it shows error on usage:

<FormInput> misses props: type, model-value

Comment: `type` prop should probably have a default value "text" (fixed). Both examples in "Usage" section pass a `modelValue` tho...

Comment: Still:

<FormInput> misses props: model-value

Comment: Are you using my exact code or still using your old code ie. `<FormInput v-bind="args" />` ?

Comment: So i used ur whole code:

1) First usage code shows error with model-value....2) Second usage code works but still not saving data in modelValue or value..and p-filled not added either...

Comment: After adding ur whole code in Vue dev console it still shows:

modelValue: undefined , even after i inputted text in input box.

Comment: You must be doing something wrong. It is working - just run added demo...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236440/discussion-between-dnd2k21-and-michal-levy).